# adding timer events with event_base_loop

Tags: linux, libevent

my ebase thread perform the following loop
    constexpr int kFlag = EVLOOP_ONCE;
    while ((res = event_base_loop(ebase_, kFlag)) == 1) {
      yield();
    }

and the other (main) thread adds periodic timer event. It adds the event *after* the ebase thread calls `event_base_loop`.

```
event* ev = event_new(base(), -1, EV_PERSIST | EV_TIMEOUT, &PeriodicCb, data);
CHECK(0 == event_add(ev, &tv));
```

However, I see that this timer event does not run. If I change `kFlag` from `EVLOOP_ONCE` to 0 it does run well. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is in the event base loop. The right code is like this:

```
while ((res = event_base_loop(ebase, EVLOOP_ONCE)) >= 0) {
  if (start_cancel)
    break;
}
```

i.e. it should continue rolling with return value no less than 0 and not just 1.